# nmap localhost UDP scan fails, even though netcat is listening

Tags: nmap, udp

I open two terminal windows on my linux box. On one, I have netcat listen to a UDP port and on other I nmap -sU that port. Netcat receives the connection and the data, but nmap reports the udp port closed. I also see an ICMP port unreachable in nmap logs (not sure why OS is sending it). I've tried --max-retries 1 also. Any advice is much appreciated.

```
$ nc -l -u -p 12345 -v
listening on [any] 12345 ...
connect to [127.0.0.1] from localhost [127.0.0.1] 65188
test
```

In a different window

```
$ sudo nmap -Pn -sU -p 12345 localhost --data-string test -vvv --packet-trace

Starting Nmap 6.49BETA4 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-15 19:29 EDT
Warning: Hostname localhost resolves to 2 IPs. Using 127.0.0.1.
Initiating UDP Scan at 19:29
Scanning localhost (127.0.0.1) [1 port]
SENT (0.0481s) UDP 127.0.0.1:65188 > 127.0.0.1:12345 ttl=42 id=17191 iplen=32 
RCVD (0.0479s) UDP 127.0.0.1:65188 > 127.0.0.1:12345 ttl=42 id=17191 iplen=32 
SENT (1.0482s) UDP 127.0.0.1:65189 > 127.0.0.1:12345 ttl=59 id=50254 iplen=32 
RCVD (1.0482s) UDP 127.0.0.1:65189 > 127.0.0.1:12345 ttl=59 id=50254 iplen=32 
RCVD (1.0482s) ICMP [127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Port 12345 unreachable (type=3/code=3) ] IP [ttl=64 id=4558 iplen=60 ]
Completed UDP Scan at 19:29, 1.20s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up, received user-set (0.000067s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Scanned at 2015-10-15 19:29:52 EDT for 2s
PORT      STATE  SERVICE REASON
12345/udp closed unknown port-unreach ttl 64

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.25 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 2 (64B) | Rcvd: 3 (124B)
```

Answer (score 2):

With netcat:

> In listen mode,  controls the address on which Ncat listens; if
>   you omit it, Ncat will bind to all local interfaces (INADDR_ANY). If
>   the port number is omitted, Ncat uses its default port 31337.
>   Typically only privileged (root) users may bind to a port number lower
>   than 1024. A listening TCP server normally accepts only one connection
>   and will exit after the client disconnects. Combined with the
>   --keep-open option, Ncat accepts multiple concurrent connections up to the connection limit. With --keep-open (or -k for short), the server
>   receives everything sent by any of its clients, and anything the
>   server sends is sent to all of them. **A UDP server will communicate
>   with only one client (the first one to send it data), because in UDP
>   there is no list of “connected” clients.**

So, when nmap will try the connection, nc will exit after the first packet received. But nmap, for testing a port, will send several packets. So the second packet will be lost and nmap will consider the port cloased, and moreover, your OS will send a ICMP port unreachable for the second test.
[image]

If you want to test your UDP ports and have a `open` result in nmap, you must force nmap to do only one connection: `nmap -Pn -sU -p 12345 localhost -vvv --max-retries 0`

Answer (score 0):

netcat only allows one connection at a time. ncat may allow multiple simultaneous "connections". I see the expected scan result with --max-retries 0.

Comment: this worked for me as well